# Configuring Postgresql 9.1 and PostGIS 2 on Ubuntu 13

Tags: postgresql, aws

I'm following [this manual](http://hackgeo.com/cloud-computing/amazon-web-services/configuring-postgresql-9-1-and-postgis-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-in-amazon-aws) to Configuring Postgresql 9.1 and PostGIS 2 on Ubuntu 13 in Amazon AWS, when executing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get lot of errors and warnings for example:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sharpie/forscience/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd‌​64/Packages 404 Not Found,
```

I saw this question and tried this

```
wget -O ~/fixpackage https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8850924/fixpackage; chmod +x   ~/fixpackage; sudo ~/fixpackage
```

it didn't work, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Sharpie's "For Science" PPA has packages only for Ubuntu Precise. You are running on Raring Ringtail (13.04). That is why it's throwing a 404 Not Found. Remove this PPA

`sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:sharpie/for-science`

Then like I've explained in [my blog post](http://gingerjoos.com/blog/code/installing-postgis-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail) add the PostGIS ppa

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`

and then install the postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0-scripts package

`sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1-postgis-2.0-scripts`

This should install everything from postgresql-server to the required PostGIS packages. After you're done you should be able to connect to a database with psql and be able to run this

`create extension postgis;`

If this works, then you should be good to go.